# Cypress with an Ionic app: cannot access ion-select-option because it is "not visible"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cypress

I have a have an ionic/angular app which contains a particular form-control as follows:

```
<ion-select #typeLst interface="alert" name="typeCode" formControlName="typeCode" okText="OK" cancelText="Dismiss" placeholder="Choose a firm type">
      <ion-select-option value="EPFIRMI001">Informal</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="EPFIRMF001">Formal/Ltd.</ion-select-option>
 </ion-select>
```

In my cypress test, I can navigate to the page and do other things on it but when I try to select a specific item on the "select" cypress is 'aware' of it but cannot access it.

Cypress code:

```
cy.get('ion-select[name="typeCode"]').click()

cy.get('ion-select-option[value="EPFIRMF001"]').click()
```

Cypress error:

```
Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:

<ion-select-option _ngcontent-dqd-c137="" value="EPFIRMF001" ng-reflect-value="EPFIRMF001" role="option" id="ion-selopt-1" class="md hydrated">Formal/...</ion-select-option>

This element <ion-select-option#ion-selopt-1.md.hydrated> is not visible because it has CSS property: display: none

Fix this problem, or use `{force: true}` to disable error checking.
```

N.B:

- changing the interface type of the ion-select (e.g. to 'popover') makes a slight difference as follows:

  - using `{force: true}` + `interface='popover'` allows Cypress to "pass" this step but it does not actually "click" the element, so the Select list remains in foreground and the next step fails.
  - using `{force: true}` + `interface='alert'` allows Cypress to "pass" this step and the Select list is backgrounded, however the select option is not actually "selected", so the app is now in an incorrect state for the next step.

Versions:

- Angular: 9.1.9
- Browser: Chrome 79.0.3945.117
- Cypress Version: 4.9.0
- Ionic version: 6.9.3
- O/S: LinuxMint 20

**EDIT 09/08/2020**
In response (too long for a comment) to @SanjaPaskova's second suggestion:
Using select as follows: `cy.get('ion-select[name="typeCode"]').select('Formal')`
...produces following error message:

```
cy.select() can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <ion-select _ngcontent-jql-c137="" interface="alert " name="typeCode" formcontrolname="typeCode" oktext="OK" canceltext="Dismiss" placeholder="Choose a firm type" ng-reflect-interface="alert " ng-reflect-name="typeCode" ng-reflect-ok-text="OK" ng-reflect-cancel-text="Dismiss" ng-reflect-placeholder="Choose a firm type" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-valid md in-item hydrated" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="ion-sel-0-lbl">...</ion-select>
```

Ionic/Angular source is above in my original post.   This produces the below generated DHTML:

```
<ion-card-content _ngcontent-nld-c140="" class="md card-content-md hydrated"><form _ngcontent-nld-c140="" novalidate="" class="outer ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]"><ion-item _ngcontent-nld-c140="" class="ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-valid item md ion-activatable ion-focusable item-label hydrated item-interactive item-select item-has-placeholder item-has-value"><ion-label _ngcontent-nld-c140="" class="sc-ion-label-md-h sc-ion-label-md-s md hydrated" id="ion-sel-0-lbl">Type: </ion-label><ion-select _ngcontent-nld-c140="" interface="alert
    " name="typeCode" formcontrolname="typeCode" oktext="OK" canceltext="Dismiss" placeholder="Choose a firm type" ng-reflect-interface="alert
    " ng-reflect-name="typeCode" ng-reflect-ok-text="OK" ng-reflect-cancel-text="Dismiss" ng-reflect-placeholder="Choose a firm type" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-valid md in-item hydrated" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="ion-sel-0-lbl"><ion-select-option _ngcontent-nld-c140="" value="EPFIRMI001" ng-reflect-value="EPFIRMI001" role="option" id="ion-selopt-0" class="md hydrated">Informal</ion-select-option><ion-select-option _ngcontent-nld-c140="" value="EPFIRMF001" ng-reflect-value="EPFIRMF001" role="option" id="ion-selopt-1" class="md hydrated">Formal/Ltd.</ion-select-option><input type="hidden" class="aux-input" name="typeCode" value="EPFIRMI001"></ion-select></ion-item><ion-item _ngcontent-nld-c140="" class="ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-valid item md ion-focusable item-label hydrated item-interactive item-input"><ion-label _ngcontent-nld-c140="" class="sc-ion-label-md-h sc-ion-label-md-s md hydrated" id="ion-input-1-lbl">Company name:</ion-label><ion-input _ngcontent-nld-c140="" formcontrolname="name" ng-reflect-name="name" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-valid sc-ion-input-md-h sc-ion-input-md-s md hydrated"><input class="native-input sc-ion-input-md" aria-labelledby="ion-input-1-lbl" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="ion-input-1" placeholder="" type="text"></ion-input></ion-item><ion-item _ngcontent-nld-c140="" class="ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-valid item md ion-focusable item-label hydrated item-interactive item-input"><ion-label _ngcontent-nld-c140="" class="sc-ion-label-md-h sc-ion-label-md-s md hydrated" id="ion-input-2-lbl">Tax ID (NUIT):</ion-label><ion-input _ngcontent-nld-c140="" formcontrolname="taxId" ng-reflect-name="taxId" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-valid sc-ion-input-md-h sc-ion-input-md-s md hydrated"><input class="native-input sc-ion-input-md" aria-labelledby="ion-input-2-lbl" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="ion-input-2" placeholder="" type="text"></ion-input></ion-item><ion-fab-button _ngcontent-nld-c140="" class="md ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrated"><ion-icon _ngcontent-nld-c140="" name="checkmark-outline" ng-reflect-name="checkmark-outline" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="checkmark outline"></ion-icon></ion-fab-button></form></ion-card-content>
```

**EDIT 02/05/2021**
The solution below from @VégerLóránd works, however note that when I have finally had a use case which allowed me to test it, my stack had upgraded to the following:

Versions:

- Angular: 11.2.6
- Browser: Chrome 90.0.4430.93
- Cypress Version: 6.7.1
- Ionic version: 5.29.0
- O/S: LinuxMint 20

I tested the below solution for `interface="alert"`.   I also modified it as below for `interface="action-sheet"`and this worked too.

```
        cy.get('[cy-data=type] > ion-select').should((e) =>
        {
            const [dom] = e.get();
            dom.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').click();
        });
        cy.contains('.action-sheet-button', 'Your location name').click();
        //no need to click 'OK' when interface="action-sheet"
```

Comment: Dont know much about angular here but do we have interface as "confirm" ?  As cypress is handling alerts and confirm automatically in my understanding. In case of confirm popups you can use cypress.on() and return true or false for selecting either option . Just a wild guess ..give it a try .

Comment: DId you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @D.Hodges yes, see my edit EDIT 02/05/2021 and the top-voted answer below from végér-lorand . I added another answer below showing exactly how this ended up in production code - very minor differences from the original answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I resolved it, maybe it can help to you as well.
I wrapped **ion-select** with an **ion-item** element and added **cy-data='location'** attribute to it.

```
<ion-item class="ion-no-padding ion-margin-horizontal" cy-data="location">
  <ion-label color="primary">{{ 'location' | translate }}</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="location" [disabled]="locationDisabled" >
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let location of locations" value="{{location._id}}">{{location.name}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

In the test file this is how you can access to the select:

```
cy.get('[cy-data=location] > ion-select').should((e) => {
  const [dom] = e.get();
  dom.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').click();
});
cy.contains('.alert-radio-label', 'Your location name').click();
cy.contains('OK').click();
```

In my case after i clicked the button in the shadowRoot (so the select drop down list itself) the select list appears with location names and with a button what contains OK. So if you have different scenario you need to change these details.

Comment: Thanks.   Since my OQ, we have generally moved away from using ion-select.   Partly because of this problem, partly also because it's UI is cumbersome for the user with large lists.    Now what we generally do is implement a custom "type-ahead plus dropdown" reusable component, for each "lookup in a list" scenario.    However I am going to try your solution anyway, since you made the effort to write an answer.   Give me a couple of weeks to find the cycles, then I will confirm if this works.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @d-hodges for the poke.  Here is how we eventually got it to work, at least for `<ion-select interface="action-sheet">` - this is based on the answer from @VégerLóránd

### Form Control code

```
<ion-select formControlName="type" interface="action-sheet" placeholder="{{'Product Type' | translate}}">
                        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let t of productTypes" value="{{t.code}}">{{t.description}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

### Cy E2E code to select 'Beverage' (one of the possible user-visible values on the description).

```
cy.get('[cy-data=type] > ion-select').should((e) =>
{
     const [dom] = e.get();
     dom.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').click();
});
cy.contains('.action-sheet-button', 'Beverage').click();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can invoke showing of element if is hidden, like this:

```
cy.get('ion-select-option[value="EPFIRMF001"]').invoke('show');
```

and then you can click it:

```
cy.get('ion-select-option[value="EPFIRMF001"]').click()
```

Comment: Thanks @SanjaPaskova .   I tried this but it still does not cause the desired option to be selected.

Comment: Try with force click on using this code: cy.get('css of drop down').select('Formal'). And please share complete html with drop down selector

Comment: Dear @SanjaPaskova, I have updated the OP with the extra info you requested, as it was too long for a comment.   N.B. trying cy.get('css of drop down').select('Formal') also did not work as the drop down is not implement as a standard HTML <select>.